# MPMusicPlayerController doesn't skip to the next item automatically after using a predicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmusicplayercontroller, mpmediaquery

i'm developing a music player app.I have a tableView that contains the songs names of the ipod library.My problem is that when i select a cell it plays a specific song but when that song is completed it doesn't skip to the next item automatically.
This is my code when i select a cell:

```
MPMediaQuery *mq  = [MPMediaQuery songsQuery];
MPMediaPropertyPredicate *songNamePredicate = [MPMediaPropertyPredicate               
predicateWithValue:[songsTitle objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]     
forProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
[mq addFilterPredicate:songNamePredicate];
[mp setQueueWithQuery:mq];
[mp play];
```

i really need your help.Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't skip to the next song because the playback queue only has one item. At launch, set the playback queue to the entire songs query. Also create an array of `MPMediaItem`s using the `items` property of `MPMediaQuery`:

```
MPMediaQuery *songsQuery = [MPMediaQuery songsQuery];
self.songs = songsQuery.items;
[self.musicPlayer setQueueWithQuery:songsQuery];
```

In `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`, have the music player play the selected item using `MPMusicPlayerController`'s `setNowPlayingItem:` method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MPMediaItem *song = self.songs[indexPath.row];
    [self.musicPlayer setNowPlayingItem:song];
    [self.musicPlayer play];
}
```

Here is a sample project that demonstrates this:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1990969/SongsPlayerTableView.zip